# Who has accessed a team project in TFS?

Tags: tfs

How can I see who has accessed files in a team project in TFS? Normal View History only shows you check ins. And exporting the Audit Log from TFS doesn't show you this info. I am interested in knowing who has made a read/get latest access on a specific team project.

This needs to be documented for my QA department. Are there any TFS SQL scripts that can show this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, we **do not have this kind record** of User's each operation such as read/get latest on a specific team project.

As you have mentioned history command will only displays the revision history of one or more files or folders. It only related to each changeset(checked in files).

Audit logs basically display some modify operation in TFS will also not include any access info at present.

Dig into sql database to query such information maybe a solution. However, highly not recommend to do this, since it may cause some potential risks of your database. And it will also lose support from Microsoft.

This should be a feature quest, you could submit it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea). Our PM will kindly review any suggestion.